# SpEL expression to utilize "contains()" string method

Tags: java, string, spring, spring-el

I am trying to utilize String.contains() in order to dynamically create the value for a field based upon the name of a file stored in the jobExecutionContext. The key/value (file=>nameOfFile.txt) pair definitely exists in the context because I am utilizing it in other places.

I am trying to do this with the folllowing SpEL expression:

```
<property name="subject" value="#{((String)jobExecutionContext['file']).contains('monk') ? 'Monkey' : 'Banana'} kind of file" />
```

However I'm getting the error:

```
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 9): Unexpected token.  Expected 'rparen())' but was 'identifier'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Exception because the "(String)",you can do it like this:

```
<util:map id="fruit">
    <entry key="banana" value="#{89.7}"/>
    <entry key="apple" value="efg"/>
    <entry key="orange" value="lmn"/>
</util:map>
<bean id="hello" class="com.choiwan.Hello">
    <property name="name" value="#{(fruit['banana']+'').contains('89')?'Monkey':'Banana'} kind of file"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Right - there is no cast in SpEL.

Comment: @GaryRussell The problem is that when I get the value for a key from the jobExecutionContext, the value is not returned as a string even though it was put in the jobExecutionContext as a string. Do you have any suggestions of how I might use be able to utilize it as a string again within SpEL?

Comment: If it's not a `String`, what is its type? What error do you get without the cast?

Comment: @beckah jobExecutionContext['file'] + ' '